# Opencv + Boost: Undefined references

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I have a computer vision source code that is related to find copy and move portions in a forged image. I cannot compile this source code that uses openCV and Boost, some of the errors include undefined references to OpenCv stuff, for example:.

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x3cc1): undefined reference to `cvSetZero'
```

My makefile is the following. I think I correctly indicate the boost and opencv libraries. What could be wrong?

```
# Boost library is required
BOOST_LIBS=-L/usr/include/boost -lboost_system  -lboost_random
BOOST_INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/boost
BOOST_VERSION=103500

OPENCV_INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/opencv2/ 
OPENCV_LIBS=-L/usr/include/opencv2/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_flann -lopencv_calib3d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
OPENCV_LIBS=-L/usr/lib/opencv2/ -lopencv_core ...
                   ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this directory /usr/lib/opencv2 doesn't exist. Is it bad?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if OpenCV is installed correctly and where this installation is located. Afterwards you can adjust your makefile. How to do this depends on your OS.

E.g. on Linux you might want to search for the `opencv_core.so` (e.g. via `locate -b opencv_core`).

In my case it would be

```
OPENCV_LIBS=-L/usr/lib/ -lopencv_core
```

Comment: The output of this command here is: 
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.a
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1

Comment: So, I  put OPENCV_LIBS=-L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_flann -lopencv_calib3d in Makefile but the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

if you have `pkg-config` installed, and if it knows where OpenCV is, you can try

```
OPENCV_INCLUDE=$$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)
OPENCV_LIBS=$$(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```